# Highlight syntax in start and end delimiters of region

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I'm not sure I'm using the right tool for the job here, but I'm trying to embed Lua syntax highlighting inside a block syntax. The only way I can make this work is with a `syn region`. I can find the block easily enough with a `syn match`, but trying to embed another syntax in there (e.g. with `contains=@Lua` just ends up bleeding all other the place.

This is for the [vim-sile](https://github.com/sile-typesetter/vim-sile) syntax plugin. I've managed to do something similar embedding Lua for an inline syntax where the region *end* actually is just a delimiter, so that is hilghlighted correctly. See for example:

```
\begin[papersize=a5]{document}
\nofolios
\font[family=Libertinus Serif]
\begin{script}
-- Lua comment
.myvar = "mod4=" .. 4 % 2
\end{script}

\begin{raggedright}
% sile comment
Lorem ipsum...
\end{raggedright}

\script{myvar = "mod4=" .. 4 % 2}

lorem \emph{ipsum}...
\end{document}
```

Note how the Lua code inside the `\script{...}` command works great, but the same code in the `\begin{script}...\end{script}` block does not.

[image: screenshot]

I have matches already setup for parsing the details of `\begin{<command>}` and those are nicely highlighted for *other* possible values, but specifically for `script` when Lua is going to be embedded I can't figure out how to use my regular highlighting for the delimiters *and* use them in the start/end.

```
syn region sileBlockLua matchgroup=Delimiter start="\\begin{script}"    end="\\end{script}" contains=@LUA
```

This finds the blocks and does the Lua embedding right, but the start and end text ends up as `Delimiter`.

How can I capture a region to embed another syntax, but also capture and highlgiht the start and end delimiters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This syntax rule works to highlight a Lua script inside a `\begin{script}` block:

```
syn region sileBlockLua
    \ start="\\begin{script}" end="\\end{script}"
    \ contains=sileBlock,@LUA keepend
```

You can add this rule to a file named `after/syntax/sile.vim`, for instance under your `~/.vim` directory.

The parts in bold are the ones that make it work.

With `contains=sileBlock,@LUA`, you're allowing the rules that match `\begin` and `\end` (including the following `{...}` with a command) within this region, so this will end up highlighting the delimiters appropriately.

With `keepend`, you're preventing the syntax engine from parsing Lua syntax past the end delimiter. This directive makes the match on the end delimiter stronger than the contained parts.

---

**UPDATE:** An additional improvement is to remove the end tag from the region, so that incomplete Lua syntax doesn't affect it. That can be done with the further addition of:

```
syn region sileBlockLua
    \ start="\\begin{script}" end="\\end{script}"me=s-1
    \ contains=sileBlock,@LUA keepend
```

Which indicates that the **m**atch **e**nd for that tag will be **1** character before the **s**tart of where the regular expression matches.

By having that match outside of the region, it will be unaffected by the Lua syntax rules.

(Thanks @Caleb for incorporating my suggestions into [an upstream commit](https://github.com/sile-typesetter/vim-sile/commit/93a832d491252aa90300d2b693376970270057b3)!)

Comment: Wow, thank you, and that works beautifully. It's rather amusing how the `\end{script}` delimiter changes highlighting when entering incomplete Lua code (such as when it's looking for an `end` to finish and un-closed loop, but I think that's to be expected. At least it doesn't bleed all over the rest of the file like my previous attempts.

Comment: I hope you don't mind I credited you as the [author of the code in the commit](https://github.com/sile-typesetter/vim-sile/commit/93a832d491252aa90300d2b693376970270057b3) where I added this. If you don't wish for that I'm happy to overwrite it without the credit.

Comment: Glad this worked for you! You can try changing the end tag to `end="\\end{script}"me=s-1` (change *m*atch *e*end to one character before the *s*tart of the regex), in which case the `\\end{script}` will be outside the region and might be a lot more stable... (Let me know if that helps, I can update the answer to include that too!)

Comment: Ah you're the author of the plug-in!  I didn't realize that... Yeah that's totally fine, thanks a lot for the attribution! Really happy to have helped here.

Comment: I just tried and it is indeed much more stable. Thanks for the trick.