# Highlight region between curly brackets but only when it occurs after a keyword in the same line

Tags: syntax-highlighting

So I have a language that looks something like this:

```
proc someprocess : (arg1: type1), (arg2: type2) ... |- (channel: type) =
{
    send $ch msg ;
    pay $ch {n} ;
}
```

I want the `{n}` to be highlighted however i don't want the code in the `proc` contained with `{ }` to be highlighted. i.e. only want `{..}` region to be highlighted when it occurs after `pay` or `get`.

Comment: Additonal question not that we're here: the current highlight file i made is based of a haskell file I copied and edited. It only highlights $ as an operator but is there anyway to highlight the whole word after `$`? Like I want `$ch` to be highlighted the same color as the `$` is highlighted.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your syntax right, but I wonder if you could also define the `{n}` group as having the `{` and `}` on the same line and that way you could differentiate it from the `proc` block? In any case, my answer addresses the `{...}` starting on the same line as the `pay` or `get`, so hopefully that works for you.

Comment: Regarding your follow up, please post a separate question. I suggest you should include the actual rule you're using that is matching the `$`, since it's easier to give you a better suggestion on how to tweak it if we actually know what it is... Cheers!

Comment: You *might* be able to steal an idea from the shell syntax files for `$var`

Answer (score 2):

Your don't provide full spec for your language. But whenever possible, contained-matches should be preferred. I.e. something like this:

```
syn match xPayOrGet /pay\|get/ skipwhite nextgroup=xPayGetAfter
syn match xPayGetAfter /[^;]\+;/ contains=xPayGetBraces contained
syn match xPayGetBraces /{\a\+}/ contained
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion here is to use a zero-width look-behind match to look up the specific keywords you're after (`pay` and `get`) and only consider the region when it's in that same context.

Example:

```
syntax region myGroup
  \ start=+\(\<\(pay\|get\)\>.*\)\@<={+
  \ end=+}+
  ...
```

See [`:help /\@<=`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%40%3C%3D) for details on this operator, which performs the zero-width look-behind for the pattern that includes `pay` or `get`.

Note that the documentation will recommend that you generally use `\zs` instead, to mark the beginning of a match, but that doesn't work here since you'll want to have the `pay` or `get` and other components such as the `$ch` to match other groups. Using a pattern that matches those elements without a zero-width look-behind would fail to match them to other groups, even if the `\zs` means only the `{` would be highlighted with the current group. (For more details, see question [“Syntax highlighting with multiple matches with `\zs`”](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/22429/18609).)

Comment: A recent question I answered used the same technique, maybe take a look there too for more context: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/31030/18609

Comment: How the heck did you get so good at the syntax rules 

Comment: @Ben A lot of trial and error... I think there was also one specific question here (don't recall exactly which) that took me on a deep dive on the syntax engine...

Comment: Like this one, I seem to remember it took quite a bit of research: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/22293/18609

Comment: And it looks like I've addressed the issue with `\zs` in a syntax pattern in the past too: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/22431/18609

Comment: Yeah, my own answer on that last one has a link to an answer with a link in the comments that also deals with it